# How to ignore "broken pipe" exception in nim

Tags: nim-lang

I'm writing a CLI program, and when I execute the binary like `program | head` I get:

```
Error: unhandled exception: errno: 32 `Broken pipe` [IOError]
```

I'd like to silence this exception and tried to add:

```
import posix
signal(SIG_PIPE, SIG_IGN)
```

in my main procedure, but this didn't silence the error. The program uses `threadspool`, calling another procedure to analyze a pool of input lines. (I don't know if this is relevant to the question)

UPDATE:

- This is my non-working program: https://pastebin.com/aQaRgfXR (threads spawned with `responses.add(spawn parseArray(readspool, mergeOptions))`)
- This is the full error:

```
/Users/telatina/miniconda3/nim/lib/pure/concurrency/threadpool.nim(377) slave
/Users/telatina/git/nim-stuff/orf/src/porfidus.nim(307) parseArrayWrapper
/Users/telatina/git/nim-stuff/orf/src/porfidus.nim(247) parseArray
/Users/telatina/miniconda3/nim/lib/system/io.nim(155) checkErr
/Users/telatina/miniconda3/nim/lib/system/io.nim(138) raiseEIO
Error: unhandled exception: errno: 0 `Undefined error: 0` [IOError]
```

Comment: can you give some more context about what you're doing in program.nim? minimal version that produces the error?

Comment: This is the current program https://pastebin.com/aQaRgfXR but in general, I make CLI tools that can print a number of lines to STDOUT and it's common to use them with "head", so my problem is quite general

Answer (score 4, accepted):

building on @julian-fondren 's answer and your code i was able to replicate your error.

```
import os, posix, threadpool
signal(SIG_PIPE, SIG_IGN)

proc noise =
  for i in 0 ..< int(1e6):
    stdout.write($i & '\n')

threadpool.spawn noise()
threadpool.spawn noise()
threadpool.sync()
```

for those following along.

you're using `stdout.write` in your code as well, which [may throw an IO Exception](https://nim-lang.org/docs/io.html#write%2CFile%2Ccstring)
since you use `SIG_IGN` the thread does not stop running when it receives the `SIG_PIPE` but continues to call `stdout.write` on a broken pipe, which throws the exception.

To fix this I've found three options

1. **Handle the Exception**

   This is the most general solution to any situation where your code panics with "Error: unhandled exception"

   [to handle an exception in Nim](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#exception-handling) use `try` and `except`.

`stdout.write($i & '\n')` becomes

```
try:
  stdout.write($i & '\n')
except IOError:
  #handle it by ending the program
  quit()
  #or ignore it with
  #discard
```

2. **Handle the signal**
   On my machine using `SIG_DFL` results in the thread terminating silently, thus behaving as you want but this is platform dependent.  So you can also register your own signal handler (sorry about the ugly cast)

```
#signal(SIG_PIPE,SIG_DFL)
signal(SIG_PIPE,cast[typeof(SIG_IGN)](proc(signal:cint) =
    stderr.write("handled sigpipe\n")
    quit()
  ))
```

3. **Just use echo**
   `echo`, unlike `stdout.write`  does not throw exceptions, so for this situation it's probably your easiest fix

Comment: Thank you so much. I opted for exception handling as I use writeLine not to have the newline at the end (or is there an `echo` option to do so?)

Answer (score 2):

With nim 1.2.6 and the following program (don't take it for good style):

```
import os, posix, threadpool
signal(SIG_PIPE, SIG_IGN)

proc noise =
  for i in 0 ..< int(1e6):
    echo i

threadpool.spawn noise()
threadpool.spawn noise()
threadpool.sync()
```

When run as follows it clearly ignores the EPIPE and is clearly printing from multiple threads (as both 60s are seen and then there's a delay as both threads reach the end of the loop):

```
$ ./brokenpipe |grep -m2 -F 60
60
60
```

With the `signal` call commented out, the last command throws an error:

```
$ ./brokenpipe |grep -m2 -F 60
60
60
Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/jfondren/.choosenim/toolchains/nim-1.2.6/lib/pure/concurrency/threadpool.nim(377) slave
/home/jfondren/nim/learn/brokenpipe.nim(8) noiseWrapper
/home/jfondren/nim/learn/brokenpipe.nim(6) noise
/home/jfondren/.choosenim/toolchains/nim-1.2.6/lib/system/io.nim(648) echoBinSafe
SIGPIPE: Pipe closed.
```

So your solution appears to work, and you're really going to need a minimal example of the problem that isn't fixed by it.

Comment: Well, your example works perfectly so I was wrong in thinking I was missing something obvious. I added the full code, maybe the problem is in the way I spawn threads?